How to exract raw point cloud data from pg pointcloud's pcpatch in postgis?
I have enabled postgis, pointcloud_postgis and pointcloud extensions in postgres(16.4).
And using pdal writers.pgpointcloud, I have inserted point cloud data in database. There are 2 columns in table: id, pa. pa is of type pcpatch(type from pg pointcloud).
Now I want to fetch this data in java using spring jdbc template.
Code to read the data:
Long id = 1L;
PointCloud data = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM my_pointcloud WHERE id=?",
             BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(PointCloud.class), id);

This fetches pcpatch as a large string.
How can I extract raw point data from this string format of data?
